# how to get submitted data in onSuccess method that is passed when trigger function called in swr

Tags: typescript, next.js, swr

is there any way to get submitted data into onSuccess method when i am using useSWRMutation hook.

this is my submit function

```
  const handleCreateQna = (
    event: FormSubmitEvent,
    { parentId, msgId }: CreateQnaParamsType
  ) => {
    const values = msgValues[msgId];
    event.preventDefault();
    setCreatedQnaId(msgId);
    createQnaTrigger({
      comments: values.comments,
      userId,
      courseId,
      parentId,
      assetUrl: [],
    });
  };
```

i want to get `parentId` in the onSuccess method to reset a value of state

```
const {
    error: createQnaError,
    data: createdQnaData,
    trigger: createQnaTrigger,
    isMutating: createQnMutating,
  } = useSWRMutation('/api/user', fetcher, {
    onSuccess: (response, ) => {
      // set default value of the submited parentId
      setMsgValues((pre) => ({
        ...pre,
        [parentId]: qnaInitialValue,
      }));
      // revalidate the Q&A list
      mutate(Api.getQnaByCourseId(courseId));
    },
  });
```